# My knockback effect is not working due to how the players velocity is being calculated with horizontalInput

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In my Unity2D game, I have a player that can move horizontally based on players input with the left or right keys. The players movement is handled by a `PlayerController` script I have attached below. I have an enemy, thats a evil mushroom, that spawns on the right side, and just moves until it collides with the player or the player dodges it. This mushroom movement, is done with the `MushroomMovement` script below.

My issue is that the knockback effect is not working as intended at all. When the `PlayerController` script is disabled, the knockback effect works as intended and looks great. When it is not disabled, and I can move the player around, the knockback effect does not work at all, and if it does it gives the player the tiniest vertical jump effect, like practically unnoticeable and looks almost like a jitter.

The only thing I could think of being the issue, is the way the `playersRb.velocity` is being calculated with the 1horizontalInput1. It is doing it every 1FixedUpdate1 frame.

So lets say the player is hit, the knockback effect is triggered, the players velocity is changed inside the knockback method, but as soon as thats applied the next frame changes the players velocity with `playerRb.velocity = new Vector2(horizontalInput * movementSpeed, playerRb.velocity.y);`, reseting the velocity entirely, making the knockback effect not work as intended.

The `playerRb.velocity = new Vector2(horizontalInput * movementSpeed, playerRb.velocity.y);` is the only thing I can imagine is effecting the knockback effect, but I see no way around this. I do not want to move my player with `AddForce` or translating its position. Even when I do the knockback to be a impulse `AddForce`, the same undesired effect is happening.

The only potential solution I can think of is disabling the movement of the player for a second or so after the knockback with a `isKnockBacked` boolean, and only allowing the player to move and read the horizontalInput when the knockback boolean is not true. This is not a desired effect at all in my case.

Is there really no other way to handle this issue without the boolean?

**PlayerController.cs**

```
public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Rigidbody2D playerRb;
    public float movementSpeed;
    private float horizontalInput;
    private bool isGrounded;
    public float jumpForce = 5f;
    private Animator playerAnimator;

    void Start()
    {
        playerRb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        playerAnimator = transform.Find("Visuals").GetComponent<Animator>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        horizontalInput = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        playerRb.velocity = new Vector2(horizontalInput * movementSpeed, playerRb.velocity.y);

        bool isMoving = (horizontalInput != 0);
        playerAnimator.SetBool("isMoving", isMoving);

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.UpArrow) && isGrounded)
        {
            isGrounded = false;
            playerRb.velocity = new Vector2(playerRb.velocity.x, jumpForce);
        }
    }

    void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Ground"))
        {
            isGrounded = true;
        }
    }
}
```

**MushroomMovement.cs**

```
public class MushroomMovement: MonoBehaviour
{
    private Rigidbody2D mushroomRb;
    private float movementSpeed = 2f;
    private bool isMoving = true;

    void Start()
    {
        mushroomRb= GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (isMoving)
        {
            mushroomRb.velocity = new Vector2(-movementSpeed, mushroomRb.velocity.y);
        }
    }

    void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Player"))
        {
            Rigidbody2D playerRb = other.gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
            PlayerController playerController = other.gameObject.GetComponent<PlayerController>();

            float knockbackForce = 10f; // Adjust the force as per your needs

            // Calculate the direction of knockback (mostly horizontal)
            Vector2 knockbackDirection = (other.transform.position - transform.position).normalized;

            // Apply knockback force to the player
            playerRb.velocity = knockbackDirection * knockbackForce;
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: knockback would be realistic if it was current velocity + a force of knock back.. as obviously the knockback doesnt last forever, so you dont really want to just adjust velocity but,  not knowing your game if a fireball hits you you and you are running forward an immediate detrement to the speed of forward movement even if it doesnt succeed in pushing you back would be expected